# Complex Nested SQL Query

Tags: sql

**UPDATE** I will debug my question and re-post it with more elaboration! I apologize for the confusion!

**UPDATE** Everyone who commented or posted an answer i will link you to my re-posting, thank you for taking the time to check my question and comment/answer!

I will make my question simple and straight to the point; The block of code below generates a syntax error when i include the first three subqueries.

What am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
      parent1.parent1_id,
      parent1.child1_id,
      parent1.child2_id,
      parent1.child3_id,
      parent2.parent2_id,
      parent2.child1_id,
      parent2.child2_id,
      parent2.child3_id
   FROM 
      parent1
         LEFT JOIN 
         ( SELECT 
                 child1.child1_id, 
                 child1.child1_content
              FROM 
                 child1 
              WHERE 
                 child1.child1_id = parent1.child1_id ) child1
         ( SELECT 
                 child1_extras.child1_extrasID, 
                 child1_extras.child1_extrasContent
              FROM 
                 child1_extras
              WHERE 
                 child1_extras.child1_id = child1.child1_id )
            ON parent1.child1_id = child1.child1_id
         LEFT JOIN child2
         ( SELECT 
                 child2.child2_id, 
                 child2.child2_content
              FROM 
                 child2 
              WHERE
                 child2.child2_id = parent1.child2_id )
         ( SELECT 
                 child2_extras.child2_extrasID, 
                 child2_extras.child2_extrasContent
              FROM 
                 child2_extras
              WHERE 
                 child2_extras.child2_id = child2.child2_id )
            ON parent1.child2_id = child2.child2_id
         LEFT JOIN child3
         ( SELECT 
                 child3.child3_id, 
                 child3.child3_content
              FROM 
                 child3
              WHERE 
                 child3.child3_id = parent1.child3_id )
         ( SELECT 
                 child3_extras.child3_extrasID, 
                 child3_extras.child3_extrasContent 
              FROM 
                 ( SELECT 
                         comments.comment_id, 
                         comments.comment
                      FROM 
                         comments 
                      WHERE 
                         comments.child3_extrasID = child3_extras.child3_extrasID ) child3_extras
           JOIN child3 
              ON child3_extras.child3_id = child3.child3_id )

              ON parent1.child3_id = child3.child3_id
           LEFT JOIN followers
              ON parent1.user_id = followers.followed_id
              AND parent1.parent1_timestamp > followers.follower_timestamp
              AND parent1.parent1_id NOT IN ( SELECT removed.isub_rmv FROM removed )
              AND parent1.parent1_hide = false
   WHERE 
      followers.follower_id = {$_SESSION['info']}
      {$portname_clause}
   ORDER BY 
      parent1.parent1_timestamp DESC
      LIMIT {$postnumbers} 
   OFFSET 
      {$offset}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing wrong?  You are writing queries that are too complicated, without testing the component parts of the query first.  Simplify and extend is a good model for complex SQL.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you query is non-standard SQL)

Comment: *What am i doing wrong?* - really? The way you are asking questions!

Comment: Well, I did not want to be harsh, therefore some hints: Specify the RDBMS you are using (product and version), specify the error you get, try to out-comment everything which does not produce the error. In other words: reduce this to the part which does not work. And please: Do not expect foreigners to spend their leisure time on such a question...

Comment: `LEFT JOIN child1
(SELECT ` is a syntax error, even without the backtics.

Comment: I apologize for the bad format, i'm not familiar with the tools here, i'm still checking all the responses and comments i however want to refer to something. The query works just fine until i include the subqueries from the line LEFT JOIN `child1` to the line LEFT JOIN `child3` without these subqueries there is no syntax error! I stated this in my question above!

Comment: Well, you cannot expect a query to stay syntactically correct after inserting a random block of sql (or text, or whatever) into it.

Comment: I would not call it random block of sql, i newly started studying subqueries and i did not get the hang of the concept yet. Perhaps if i explain why i need subqueries for you will have better understanding about my code above, but first let me point out to some facts; My original query successfully joins around 30 different tables, i only added the subqueries here to simply the issue. And here is why i want the subqueries for. each table of the 30 table has records and each record has comments in a table called comments. subqueries are suppose to come in handy here.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is all over your syntax.  I reformatted your query some, but don't know exactly what refers to what.  As was stated in a comment, simplify your queries individually to find out if they work, THEN add to the next in the chain.

The biggest example to clarify is joining to other tables.  Whenever joining, you do the query and assign it an alias name reference.  THAT Alias is the basis to the rest of the query.  Do not confuse an alias WIHTIN a sub-select to the outer query.  Without doing your exact query, look into the following

```
SELECT 
      parent1.parent1_id, etc, etc, etc
   FROM 
      parent1
         LEFT JOIN 
         ( SELECT 
                 child1.child1_id, 
                 child1.child1_content
              FROM 
                 child1 
              WHERE 
                 child1.child1_id = parent1.child1_id ) CHILD1
```

The lower-case "child1" INNER query is NOT the same as the OUTER upper case "CHILD1" as sampled above here.  What I THINK you are trying to get is more of the following.  Also note I am applying ALIASES to help confirm the difference between the ACTUAL table name vs whatever COULD be subquery conditions.

```
SELECT 
      P1.parent1_id, 
      C1.child1_content,
      C1X.child1_extrasID, 
      C1X.child1_extrasContent
   FROM 
      parent1 P1
         LEFT JOIN child1 C1
            on P1.child1_id = C1.child1_id
         LEFT JOIN child1_extras C1X
            on P1.child1_id = C1X.child1_id
```

Notice each additional table is joined from a possible previous.  I also try to always have me left-side table (first within the query) joined or left-joined to the second alias result key ID.

Try the above simplified sample query with a few fixed criteria just to see if it works.  THEN apply your extra table joins, where, order by, offset, etc.

Comment: Note:you did more than a bit of formatting to the original question . You actually corrected the first occuring syntax error `LEFT JOIN child1 (SELECT`

Comment: I apologize for the terrible question and sample of code above, please read the note on the bottom of the page of my new post in the
following link and you will find out why i made such a disastrous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912668/chain-of-sql-subqueries-within-large-query-of-joins